# symfony entity function autput in twig translate

Tags: symfony, translation

In my project I have entity with atribute type, for display in twig templates I use function

```
public function getTypeString(): string
{
    $types = self::getPredefinedTypes();

    return $types[$this->type];
}

public static function getPredefinedTypes(): array
{
    return [
        self::PROJECT_TYPE_ONETIME => 'onetime',
        self::PROJECT_TYPE_ONGOING => 'ongoing',
    ];
}
```

im messages.cs.yaml i have

```
project.type.onetime: první typ
project.type.ongoing: druhý typ
```

and in twig templates I have

```
{{'project.type.' ~ project.getTypeString() | trans }}
```

but this dont display the translation

How I translate with key this example?

Comment: What happens instead? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: display key string i.e project.type.onetime. When I use the same string to transate in controller the string wa corectly translate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are translating only return value of project.getTypeString()

```
{{ 'project.type.' ~ project.getTypeString() | trans }} # only value of project.getTypeString() is being translated
{{ ('project.type.' ~ project.getTypeString())|trans }} # equals 'project.type.onetime'|trans
```